# Java raytracer increase CPU usage

Tags: java, raytracing

I tried to implement a raytracer in Java and everything works fine. 
Once, I was rendering a scene and I checked the CPU-Usage of my program.
Every virtual core was being used but the overall CPU-Usage was around 22-23%

I know that when I was rendering something with Cinema4D every virtual core was being used 100%.

How could I archive this? Will it make my raytracer run 4 times faster? (23% -> 100%)

Comment: Technically, you can flood your system with useless cycle-burning code, and get your CPU usage to 100%. Wouldn't exactly work faster after this. And do note, that CPU usage doesn't mean that your program runs faster or better.

Comment: But for example: I've got 8 virtual cores on my pc. Could I create 8 Threads and set their priority to extrem high and let each thread calculate pixel per pixel?

Comment: That depends on algorithm you're using. Certain types of computations work in parallel better than other types. If you can't isolate `n` computation blocks in your raytrace algorithm that are independent of each other, then required synchronization between your block might eat up all your CPU performance, and your app will work slower despite consuming more memory and CPU.

Comment: Re, "...and set their priority to extrem high..."  That is not what priority is for.  Setting priority higher won't increase the number of available cycles.

Comment: What is it used for then?  

According to this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940378.aspx
my thread gets more time by the processor and this increases the amount of cycles, right?

Comment: There's two different kinds of "priority," and the Java library doesn't let you choose which kind you get.  One kind--common on desktop & server systems--gives "high-priority" threads a bigger share of CPU time when there's competition. It's a relic of old time-share systems where users paid real money for CPU cycles, but still maybe useful for "balancing loads" on big servers.  The other kind is mostly found on real-time operating systems, where it is used to make sure that certain threads can react quickly to asynchronous inputs and sometimes, to insure that threads that release...

Comment: ...resources get to run before other threads that consume the same resources.

Comment: Ah! that makes sense. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely be able to get to 100% CPU usage, and all else being equal, doing so should result in faster rendering speed. That you're apparently not at 100% indicates to me that you're either not creating enough threads, or your threads are blocking on something.

I've found the sweet spot is one rendering thread per virtual core. You can use the API to detect the number of cores available at runtime, and spawn that many rendering threads. For an example of this, see [my java ray tracer](https://github.com/danielthompson/danray).

> Every virtual core was being used but the overall CPU-Usage was around 22-23%

I'm not sure what you mean by this, but you may want to dig into it using a performance profiler to better understand how your threads are using CPU. Ideally you want each of your threads to be working all the time. I use [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) to visualize process threads.

Comment: I assume my way of seeing the CPU-Usage is a little bit "old school". I checked the task manager... For now, I've only one main Thread. I am implementing multiple threads right now. I also had to check how accessing the same variables with multiple threads work when I do not change the data. A friend told me that I do not have to make my functions synchronized because I only read the Vertex positions etc.

Comment: One rendering thread per virtual core. On my machine, I have a quadcore proc with hyperthreading, so I use 8 cores.

Comment: Well I implemented multiple Threads but my code runs the fastest when I only use one single Thread. Should I use the "volatile"-identifier with my triangles?

Comment: Before making any code changes, I would use VisualVM to determine what exactly is going on with your threads. Making changes without knowing the cause of the problem is just guesswork.

Comment: Yep. I will do that tomorrow :) thank you for your help and advice!!:)

Comment: So I created a little scene with smooth shadows and had VisualVM running beside.

This was the result:
1 Thread: 26 sec   (VisualVM Screenshot): https://prnt.sc/gc4af4
2 Threads: 16 sec   (VisualVM Screenshot): https://prnt.sc/gc4b3e
3 Threads: 25 sec   (VisualVM Screenshot): https://prnt.sc/gc4c35
4 Threads: 30 sec   (VisualVM Screenshot): https://prnt.sc/gc4cv5

I think it's clear that the optimization already stops after 2 Threads being used. The Threads seem to block each other. What can I do?

Comment: Looks like your rendering threads are Threads 4, 5, 6, 7, and they are blocking (red) a significant amount of the time. This is because they are contending for some shared resource, like a lock or something. Do you have any `synchronized` code blocks or variables? Try unsynchronizing them and see what happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152653/discussion-between-daniel-a-thompson-and-luecx).